# How to read the integers from the .txt file which contains 2-D array, i am getting java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

so i have to read a matrix from .txt file, which is of the format given below.

```
problemMatrix = [[101, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 9, 40], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 28, 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70], [71, 72, 73, 7, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

i have already written code to calculate the rows and columns. I have written this code to get the integer value in [i][j] index.

```
    int [][] input= new int[rows][cols]; 
    matrix = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    matrix.useDelimiter("[ ,\r\n\t=]");
    try{    
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<cols;j++){
                input[i][j]=matrix.nextInt();
                System.out.print(input[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            }   
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

but this is giving me exception `InputMismatchException`. Any suggestions. I don't understand how to change the delimiters for scanner.
Thanks.

Comment: share content of  text.txt

Comment: Does "problemMatrix = " exist in your txt file? If yes, then it doesn't match the regex that you provided, hence the exception. Try reading this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: yes, the matrix i have given above is taken from the test.txt and it contains problem matrix

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your regex.  The regex `[ ,\r\n\t=]` means "match any of , `\r`, `\n`, `\t` or `=`.  Note that it will NOT match `[` or `]`.

You should include both `[` and `]` inside your square brackets, and make sure that they're escaped, and that should help.  You may also have an issue with multiple delimeters leading to your scanner trying to parse an empty string, so you will want your regex to match multiple of these characters together.

Comment: i used  matrix.useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
after reading more about regex.
thanks for you help joe c.